# jQuery Menu > Collapse All Not WIthin Current Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Menu *- Snippet***

```
<ul class="Menu Open">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account">
            <span class="Title">Account</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu First TeStInG">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Dashboard">
                    <span class="Title">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages">
                    <span class="Title">Messages</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Compose">
                            <span class="Title">Compose</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Profile">
                    <span class="Title">Profile</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Profile/View">
                            <span class="Title">View</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery *- Snippet***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict";

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest($('.Menu')).length) {

            if ($(e.target).closest("a").siblings("ul").length === 0) {
                console.log('Doesn\'t have Children');
            } else {
                $(e.target).closest("a").siblings("ul").show();
            }

        }

    });

});
```

**What I'm Trying To Achieve**

Without using jQuery UI, I would like to make it so that only one menu item is visible at a time on each level.

- If the user has expanded a level multiple times then clicks on a different higher level, all within should be hidden.
- If the user clicks on a same level item which expands, all other same level should be hidden.

I've tried several ways to do this, however I keep getting tied up whereas I either make things hide which shouldn't or make it so that I cannot expand anything. I've done this previously and cannot understand why I cannot do this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` but when you click on parent you will have to check if it is parent, so when you want to open you just want to open direct children but when you want to close you want to close all chidren.

```js
$("ul li ul").hide()

$('li').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  var parent = $(this)
  $(this).find('ul').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
      $(this).hide()
    } else {
      if ($(this).parent().is(parent)) {
        $(this).show()
      }
    }
  })
  $(this).siblings().children('ul').hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Menu Open">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account">
      <span class="Title">Account</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu First TeStInG">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Dashboard">
          <span class="Title">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages">
          <span class="Title">Messages</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Compose">
              <span class="Title">Compose</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Profile">
          <span class="Title">Profile</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Profile/View">
              <span class="Title">View</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly! Just minor modifications to relate to my page and I've got it working!

Comment: Great, glad i could help.

Comment: I don't suppose you could aid further please? \How could I achieve toggling `.active` too? I've got it working on the show part: `Parent.addClass("active");`, however to remove it, I am struggling.

Comment: Lets say you want active on `li`'s you can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1454/, similar is for `ul` you just need to adjust selectors a bit

Comment: `Account > Private > View > Test` makes all collapse however luckily my menu doesn't expand this far at the moment. Thank you for this, brilliant help!

Comment: I should've noticed that!